# Sonar - How to Skip Conditional Coverage on new code

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have a maven java project which has a quality gate configured to check if new line coverage is greater than 90%, but recently i am noticing even if lines are covered 100%, if there are conditions not covered, sonar treats it as a quality gate failure. how do i skip conditional coverage in sonar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "Line Coverage on New Code" instead of "Coverage on New Code" in your QG definition - this should effective rule out the condition coverage criteria.

Comment: Thank You! worked like a charm.